# Complexity of finding a root in ring P

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponential-function, primitive-roots

$G$ and $P$ are known prime.

$$b = a^G \bmod P$$

What is the complexity time of finding $a$ from $b$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the inverse $F:= G^{-1} \bmod P{-}1$ (using eg. Extended Euclidean) and then calculate $b^F \bmod P$ (exponentiation by squaring).